# How to call super() in Python 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the strangest error I have seen for a while in Python (version 3.0).

Changing the signature of the function affects whether `super()` works, despite the fact that it takes no arguments. Can you explain why this occurs?

Thanks,

Chris

```
>>> class tmp:
...     def __new__(*args):
...             super()
... 
>>> tmp()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __new__
SystemError: super(): no arguments
>>> class tmp:
...     def __new__(mcl,*args):
...             super()
... 
>>> tmp()
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html?#super) say, "The zero argument form automatically searches the stack frame for the class (`__class__`) and the first argument."  Your first example of `__new__` doesn't HAVE a first argument - it claims it can be called with zero or more arguments, so argumentless `super` is stumped. Your second example DOES have an explicit first argument, so the search in the stack frame succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

python 3.0 new super is trying to dynamically make a choice for you here, read this PEP [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) that should explain everything.